# Duplicating data when reading JSON structure using BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, unnest

I see that data is getting duplicated or missing the sequence ad creating invalid data for the JSON Structure I have.

Sample InPut Data: have two columns job_id and "conv_column" Which has below JSON structure.

[
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "WP1",
    "Name": "Well #1",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "",
    "Field": "",
    "Uwi": "",
    "Environment": "",
    "WellId": "WP1",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": "",
    "Type": "",
    "WaterDepth": "",
    "WellGeometry": "",
    "DrillFor": "",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "dd726299-26c3-447d-8367-ef1ec79d1c28",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": true
  },
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "WP2",
    "Name": "Well #2",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "",
    "Field": "",
    "Uwi": "",
    "Environment": "",
    "WellId": "WP2",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": "",
    "Type": "",
    "WaterDepth": "",
    "WellGeometry": "",
    "DrillFor": "",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "129808ad-6f07-46f3-ab70-4140e4cc92ff",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": true
  },
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "1-6HQPMA",
    "Name": "BLANCA-004",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "Ecuador",
    "Field": "BLANCA",
    "Uwi": "BLC-004",
    "Environment": "Land",
    "WellId": "0064004151",
    "Latitude": "0.311318889",
    "Longitude": "-76.17652111",
    "Type": "Development",
    "WaterDepth": "",
    "WellGeometry": "Vertical (0 - <15)",
    "DrillFor": "Oil",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "239cbe08-b691-4fe2-922a-9b55df027bff",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": false
  },
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "1-2CQM5S",
    "Name": "BLANCA-002",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "Ecuador",
    "Field": "BLANCA",
    "Uwi": "BLC-002",
    "Environment": "Land",
    "WellId": "0064004099",
    "Latitude": "0.332268889",
    "Longitude": "-76.17651833",
    "Type": "Exploration",
    "WaterDepth": "",
    "WellGeometry": "",
    "DrillFor": "Oil",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "8f7c5d6c-3c07-4c02-a2f0-37b0230df306",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": false
  },
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "1-69H44K",
    "Name": "BLANCA-003",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "Ecuador",
    "Field": "BLANCA",
    "Uwi": "BLC-003",
    "Environment": "Land",
    "WellId": "0064004139",
    "Latitude": "0.281760556",
    "Longitude": "-76.14325722",
    "Type": "Development",
    "WaterDepth": "0",
    "WellGeometry": "Deviated (15 - <60)",
    "DrillFor": "Oil",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "b8da860e-2fb6-4a46-8fd7-def7f0515d30",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": false
  },
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "1-290RHS",
    "Name": "BLANCA-001",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "Ecuador",
    "Field": "BLANCA",
    "Uwi": "BLC-001",
    "Environment": "Land",
    "WellId": "0064001507",
    "Latitude": "0.332357778",
    "Longitude": "-76.17656278",
    "Type": "Development",
    "WaterDepth": "",
    "WellGeometry": "",
    "DrillFor": "Oil",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "e8b59fcf-739d-48f4-bf7f-14619c1c9304",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": false
  },
  {
    "Source": "",
    "Number": "1-6IBUKB",
    "Name": "BLANCA-005",
    "SapNumber": "",
    "State": "",
    "Country": "Ecuador",
    "Field": "BLANCA",
    "Uwi": "BLC-005",
    "Environment": "Land",
    "WellId": "0064004159",
    "Latitude": "0.311257778",
    "Longitude": "-76.17659889",
    "Type": "Development",
    "WaterDepth": "",
    "WellGeometry": "Deviated (15 - <60)",
    "DrillFor": "Oil",
    "County": "",
    "City": "",
    "WellPlaceholderId": "719ae538-3d3e-4667-bdf0-cc2e9d2720b6",
    "IsNonMasteredWell": false
  }
]

Output:
[image]

Code I am using:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var result = jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
  if(result){return result;} 
  else {return [];}
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://dev-workspace/json_temp/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
SELECT distinct job_id,well_id,
 well_name,well_number,well_sap_number,well_field,well_uwi
from lz_fdp_op.dbm_temp_data 
left join UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column,"$.Operation.Wells[*].WellId")) Well_ID
left join UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column,"$.Operation.Wells[*].Name")) well_name
left join UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column,"$.Operation.Wells[*].Number")) well_number
left join UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column,"$.Operation.Wells[*].SapNumber")) well_sap_number
left join UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column,"$.Operation.Wells[*].Field")) well_field
left join UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column,"$.Operation.Wells[*].Uwi")) well_uwi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the function advised by @Mikhail Berlyant earlier, and I have the solution.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonparse(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
SELECT job_id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(wells, '$.WellId') AS Well_id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(wells, '$.Name') AS Well_Name
FROM temp_db.dbm_temp_data ,
UNNEST(jsonparse(JSON_EXTRACT(conv_column, '$.Operation.Wells'))) wells
```